# Why dot in front of my device is orange in organizer of xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode3.2, ios5.1, xcode-organizer, ios

I am using Xcode 3.2.6. My mac OS X version is 10.6.8. I added my new iPhone 4S in device portal and installed provisioning profile. iOS 5.1.1 is installed on my phone. I got orange dot in front of my device in organizer and this message comes when i try to add device to portal. "Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version".

How can i change that orange dot to green so i can install and check my app in my new iPhone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your 4S is running iOS5? You should update Xcode to the latest version (available on the mac app store)

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your Xcode with 4.3 at least.

Comment: i tired to install xcode 4.3.1 but its showing this message. "You have Mac OS X 10.6.8. The application requires Mac OS X 10.7.3 or later." I tried to update my OS X but it says that there is no update.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you only have the new profile installed under your provisioning tab on both the device and one the Mac duplicates will cause problems such as these although xcode needing updated may be the problem too like mentioned above try to go to the Mac app store and download it although if you aren't on lion it won't be available apple is really good about that kind of thing too.